# Mobile: Android: How to hit enter after entering a text

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, appium-android

Scenario is like:

1. There is password field where I enter a text (this is done using sendKeys)
2. Now, there is no submit/enter button
3. So I have to press enter and login to application

**Below are few ways which I searched and tried but didn't worked:**

1. `element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`
2. `element.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);`
3. I'm using java client 7.0.0 (because of some another useful features) and in that there is no pressKeys kind of methods available in it 
   https://monosnap.com/file/tjp2F86HH0kxFFU9SJKGII8fBEK45j

`driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));` (cannot use this because of Java Client 7.0.0)
`((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);` (cannot use this because of Java Client 7.0.0)

**Expected:**
After entering password, hit enter and I expect user should be logged in

**Actual:**
Tried with above few ways and after sendKeys, entered password is erased

Please let me know how can I automate this scenario.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add in EditText Xml

```
 <EditText
      android:id="@+id/etMobileNumber"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:inputType="number"
      android:imeOptions="actionDone"
      android:maxLength="10"
      android:maxLines="1" />
```

and Event code

```
   etMobileNumber.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId != 0 || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mRegisterButton.performClick(); // Your login button click
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

and other ways,
 -EditText

```
 <EditText
  android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

-OnEditorAction

```
etMobileNumber.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId != 0 || event.getAction() == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            mRegisterButton.performClick(); // Your login button click
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Dont post the same answers as others and tell what is the difference you have answered compared to others.

Answer (score 0):

You do it by setting an `OnKeyListener` on your `EditText`.

```
passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clEtAddCourse);
passwordEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            switch (keyCode)
            {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                    //.. here you get enter button of keyboard pressed event perform you action here.
                    return true;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.submit()` method also can use instead enter action.

```
element.sendKeys("password");
element.submit();
```